# Detecting that an object is repeatedly iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

Does `obj == iter(obj)` imply that `obj` isn't repeatedly iterable and vice versa? I didn't see any such wording in the docs, but according to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols#comment62722931_9884259), the standard library checks if an object is *repeatedly iterable* [by testing `if iter(obj) is obj`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ce31ee3b1e69/Lib/statistics.py#l551):

> @agf: There are parts of the Python standard library that rely on this part of the spec; [they detect whether something is an iterator/generator by testing `if iter(obj) is obj:`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ce31ee3b1e69/Lib/statistics.py#l551), because a true iterator/generator object will have `__iter__` defined as the identity function. If the test is true, they convert to `list` to allow repeated iteration, otherwise, it's assumed that the object is repeatably iterable, and they can use it as is.
>   – [ShadowRanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364696/shadowranger) [Jun 3 at 17:23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols#comment62722931_9884259)

The docs do state that if `obj` is an iterator, it's required that `iter(obj)` returns `obj`. But I don't think that's enough to conclude that non-repeatedly iterable objects can be identified using `iter(obj) is obj`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All iterators are iterables, but not all iterables are iterators.

The only [requirement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#container.__iter__) of an iterable is that it defines an `__iter__()` method which returns an iterator:

> One method needs to be defined for container objects to provide iteration support:
>
> **`container.__iter__()`**
>   Return an iterator object.

An [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) must follow the *iterator protocol*, which has two requirements:

1. It has an `__iter__()` method [that returns the object itself](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__iter__):

   > **`iterator.__iter__()`**
   >   Return the iterator object itself.
2. It has a `__next__()` method which returns the next item on each call, and, once exhausted, raises `StopIteration` [on every subsequent call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__):

   > Once an iterator’s `__next__()` method raises `StopIteration`, it must continue to do so on subsequent calls. Implementations that do not obey this property are deemed broken.

These requirements mean that iterators are never repeatable, and that you can always confirm that an iterable is an iterator (and therefore unrepeatable by definition) by confirming that `iter(obj) is obj` is `True`:

```
def is_unrepeatable(obj):
    return iter(obj) is obj
```

**However:** since the only requirement of an iterable is that `iter(obj)` returns *some* iterator, you *can't* prove that it *is* repeatable. An iterable could define an `__iter__()` method which returns an iterator with different behaviour each time it's called: for instance, it could return an iterator which iterates over its elements the first time it's called, but on subsequent calls, return an iterator which immediately raises `StopIteration`.

This behaviour would be strange (and annoying), but is not prohibited. Here's an example of a non-repeatable iterable class which is not an iterator:

```
class Unrepeatable:

    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.iterable = iterable
        self.exhausted = False

    def __iter__(self):
        if self.exhausted:
            return
        else:
            self.exhausted = True
            yield from self.iterable
```

```
>>> x = Unrepeatable([1,2,3])
>>> list(x)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list(x)
[]
>>> iter(x) is x
False
>>>
```

I wouldn't hesitate to call such a "fake iterator" badly-behaved, and I can't think of a situation where you'd find one in the wild, but as demonstrated above, it is possible.

Comment: To go further: while it's trivial to come up with a pathological counter-example, I think it's safe to assume "`iter(obj) is not obj` <=> obj is reiterable" in practice. See this [discussion](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2013-September/023241.html) by core python devs on this very issue. I've not seen an example of a non-reiterable, non-iterator iterable that isn't also either useless or nonsensical.

Comment: @shadydog: At least on Python 2.7, `urllib.urlopen` is a real-world counterexample. It returns an object with `iter(obj) is not obj`, but with file-like one-shot iteration behavior. I don't know if the Python 3 equivalent behaves the same. `iter(x) is iter(x)` is a slightly more reliable check that catches `urllib.urlopen`; I don't know of anything it fails on that anyone actually uses, but it still can't catch everything.